# How to output #defines into the output file generated by mcpp

Tags: c++

I am using mcpp (matsui cpp) to precompile my source code  which is having lot of #defines and macros. The CPP is working fine and I am getting the desired output, but for some reason, I need the #defines which is available in source file to be available also in the precompiled output. But currently the resultant only shown in precompiled output. The original #defines are gone. Anyway I want the #defines for later processing. Is it possible by any means ?

Comment: This is not possible without fundamentally changing the relationship between the preprocessor and later phases of compilation.    The preprocessor functions by doing text substitution on source code before it is compiled, so the macros themselves are no longer present during compilation, let alone present in compiled or precompiled output.     The only solution is to avoid using macros entirely, and define named variables  (e.g. `const int FOO = 1` rather than `#define FOO 1`) or inline functions.   Using macros, other than as include guards, is often considered poor practice in C++ anyway.